# RP2040 automatic BOOTSEL switching circuit

Tags: usb-device, bootstrap, rp2040

[image: Schematic]
I enjoy drawing electronic circuits and making them by hand as a hobby. (Not a major, not a job)

While writing a custom board based on the `RP2040` chip, I am trying to make it automatically reboot and boot in `USB mode` (like `firmware update` mode!!) when a specific command is sent to `USB CDC`.

First of all, I drew the circuit and would like to get some feedback. Also, I would like to know if it is possible to set the `GPIO` pin of `RP2040` to high and reboot while booting in USB mode, and if so, how to do it.

**Questions summary**

1. Feedback about my schematic: Possibility, errors, etc...
2. A way to set GPIO pins under USB mode.

**Custom board full schematic (Added)**
note that, this schematic does not contain above circuit yet.
[image: Custom board full schematic]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you put fragments of the circuit in separate boxes and show most connections with net names?  The circuit would be much clearer if you showed all the parts together, with wire connections - particularly the MODE_NQ and MODE_PQ connections between the gates.  Connecting by net names does have a place, but your circuit isn't it.

Comment: @PeterBennett I didn't want to make spagetti. Sometimes, wires make schematic too complex. And, blue boxes are for writing comment that is more readable... most net names are from RP2040 pinouts. and it really hurts my eyes to follow the lines.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're aiming for, but it seems you're looking to automate booting into flash mode, and you're trying to achieve that through manipulating the RUN and BOOTSEL pins. Is that right? In that case, are you aware of the `reset_usb_boot(0,0);` command from the C API?

Comment: @DamienD I'm newbie of `RP2040`, it was existed! lol, all of this are not needed, thanks! Is there an API to reset when USB booted?

Comment: @jayk If you're using the C/C++ SDK then this might do what you want. If you're using the Arduino SDK I'm not sure, I've never used it on the RP2040. By the way, if you flash a C SDK program on the Pico, it already comes with a built-in way to reset into flash mode from a USB command, see https://github.com/illusiaDecafish/bootselBoot

Comment: @jayk `an API to reset when USB booted` I seem to remember it resets when unmounting the USB mass storage device from the computer, but my memory is a bit hazy there.